# how to handle exceptions in python

Tags: python, exception

I get errors like this

```
return SegmentWriter(self, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whoosh/writing.py", line 502, in __init__
    raise LockError
whoosh.index.LockError
```

I would like to catch these errors with a try/except statement. So I wrote

```
try:
    do whatever causes the error
except LockError:
    print "LockError..."
    handle error
```

but this leads to a `NameError`, since `LockError` is unknown?

```
    except LockError:
NameError: global name 'LockError' is not defined
```

how do I handle these Lock errors?

Comment: Have you tried `except whoosh.index.LockError:`?

Comment: u can try `except Exception as e:` in the next line `print e`

Comment: @manojprashantk please don't suggest things like that. It's a terrible idea to catch all exceptions; only ever catch the ones you are expecting and know how to deal with.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I think they meant to help with debugging; catch all exceptions *just to be able to see the type*.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman thanks for your suggestion. But that is why i have given it as a comment rather than posting it as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First import exception in your namespace. Add this to your module:

```
from whoosh.index import LockError
```